# Check if alerts are blocked

Tags: javascript

Currently, I have:

```
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) { do something }
```

- When the message displays, and the user clicks "Ok", it's `true`.
- When the message displays, and the user clicks "Cancel", it's `false`.
- If the user checks the box "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs", the confirm will always return `false`.

Is it possible to check whether the user has checked the "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" box?

What I want to do is:

```
var dialogsPrevented = // boolean that depicts whether dialogs are being suppressed.
if (dialogsPrevented || confirm("Are you sure?")) { do something }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `Date.now()` before and after. Unless the user clicked the button within like a hundredth of a second, you can be fairly sure the dialog was blocked.

```
function checkedConfirm(query) {
    var time = Date.now();
    var response = confirm(query);
    if( response) return "TRUE";
    if( Date.now() - time > 10) return "FALSE";
    return "DIALOG_NOT_FOUND";
}
```

Adjust return values as necessary/useful.

Comment: Great solution! I'd recommend returning `true`, `false` and `null` instead of string values, though.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Probably. Or you could slap it in a class and use `checkedConfirm.OK  / checkedConfirm.CANCEL / checkedConfirm.BLOCKED`... but I just wanted to make a silly reference :D https://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_